# Python error with xarray open_rasterio function

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to read a file this netcdf file and convert it into tif file and read it using xarray

```
import xarray as xr
import geemap
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

# Step 1: Download the NetCDF file
url = 'https://github.com/giswqs/leafmap/raw/master/examples/data/wind_global.nc'
filename = 'wind_global.nc'
data = geemap.read_netcdf(filename)

# Step 2: Convert the NetCDF file to a GeoTIFF
tif = 'wind_global.tif'
geemap.netcdf_to_tif(filename, tif, variables=['u_wind', 'v_wind'], shift_lon=True)
print(data)
# Step 3: Read the GeoTIFF file using rioxarray
data = xr.open_rasterio(tif)

# Extract latitude and longitude values from the data
latitude = data.y.values
longitude = data.x.values

# Convert wind data from U/V components to magnitude and direction
u_wind = data.values[0]
v_wind = data.values[1]
wind_magnitude = np.sqrt(u_wind*2 + v_wind*2)
wind_direction = np.degrees(np.arctan2(u_wind, v_wind))

# Create a meshgrid of latitude and longitude
lon_grid, lat_grid = np.meshgrid(longitude, latitude)
```

which throws me the error
module 'xarray' has no attribute 'open_rasterio'

Answer (score 2):

`xarray.open_rasterio` was deprecated from version 0.20.0 onwards ([release notes](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/whats-new.html#id238)), and has been removed as of build 2023.04.0 ([release notes](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/whats-new.html#id19)).

The recommended replacement is `rioxarray.open_rasterio` (["Getting Started" guide](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/getting_started/getting_started.html#rioxarray)).